# Wildfly ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my application to a Wildfly Application server but I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal  org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha1:deploy (default)  on project medical-api: 
    Deployment failed: Operation failed:  {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps  that failed:" => 
    {
        "Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services"  => 
        {
            "jboss.deployment.unit.medical-api-ian.POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service  jboss.deployment.unit.medical-api-ian.POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed  to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"medical-api-ian\" Caused  by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dao.MaternityPlanDaoJpaImpl from  [Module \"deployment.medical-api-ian:main\" from Service Module  Loader] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  dao.MaternityPlanDaoJpaImpl from [Module  \"deployment.medical-api-ian:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}
        }
    }
}  -> [Help 1]
```

The class MaternityPlanDaoJpaImpl is in my folder structure I can see it clearly so I'm confused as to why it's throwing this error.

For shits and giggles I deleted the class and then it chose to throw the same exception about a different class in a different package.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What version of WildFly? I'd expect to see a `.war`, `.ear` or `.jar` at the end. Make sure you have the correct extension on the archive.

Comment: Hey sorry for delay in reply. I'm using Wildfly 8.11.0.Final. Yes the output I get is a .war file but when I try to deploy this as I've been doing all the previous times I start getting these ClassNotFound Exceptions

Comment: Does it have the .war extension? e.g. `medical-api-ian.war`

Comment: Yes I've something very similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

First, change to the version 8.2.0.Final or 9.0.0.CR2.

Many Bugs Fixed since 8.1.0-Final version.

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel

You can see examples of use here.

- https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart

Use the stable version of wildfly-maven-plugin.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Note:

Possibly you are compiling with a JDK version that is not supported by WildFly.

You may be compiling with a version and running with a version in another.

I recommend you use the latest most stable version JDK if possible.

Answer (score 0):

make a jar file using ant build and put it in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/class folder in your war folder

Comment: While this may work please create answers which are more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

use ant to compile or make jar with ant put jar files or class file in

deployment folder\war-folder\WEB_INF\lib or classes folder